# Does DASK LSFCluster support GPU?

Tags: gpu, dask, hpc, lsf

Can I specify number of GPUs by using DASK LSFCluster? I know we can specify number of cores, which means CPU only. We would like to request GPUs from the LSF scheduler. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Dask-Jobqueue allows you to add extra lines to your job script with keywords like `env_extra=`.  These might be enough for you to add custom resource requests to LSF.

Comment: Thank you MRcoklin.